# AngularJS directives how to get deeper tree nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, swiper.js

My html view looks like below:

```
<div mydirectives="options..." class='container'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <img src='{{data.img}}' class='slide' ng-repeat='..'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how I'm able to get slide objects in directives?
What I've tried was:

```
compile: function (uiSwiperConfig, $document, $timeout) {
     var me = this;
     me.$document = $document;
     return {
              preLink: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                     me.container = element;
                     me.userDefinedParams = angular.copy(scope.$eval(attrs.uiSwiper));
                     me.wrapper = element[0].querySelectorAll("."+me.params.wrapperClass);
                     me.slides = angular.element(element.find("swiper-slide"));
                  or me.slides = element[0].querySelectorAll(".slide");
                  or me.slides = me.wrapper.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    ...
      }
    }
}
```

None of them works except giving me an empty object.

Comment: Firebug showed me.container is an object and me.wrapper is a NodeList which is in lighter red colour and seems like disabled or inactive node.

Comment: Instead of using `ng-repeat`, I used several `<img>` tags and I'm able to get slides `NodeList` in directive. Why? The only difference between static `img` tag and `ng-repeat img` tag is after AngularJS compiling, there is a style class named `ng-scope` in `img` tag, which is `<img class='slide ng-scope'.../>`. But `ng-repeat` is what I need.

Comment: This `element[0].getElementsByTagName("img");` gave me slides object, but I'm unable to access any of its element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to implement this is to create an AngularJS element by using

```
angular.forEach(data.slides, function (slide) {
      var img = angular.element('<img src="'+slide.img+'"/>');
      me.wrapper.append(img);
});
```